# How can I make my function handle an exception?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a function which looks like this

```
def read_data(input_file_name):
    """ (str) -> list, list

    Read data from the path specified by the string input_file.

    Data looks like:
    18,  120
    20,  110
    22,  120
    25,  135

    Output two lists, one for each column of data.
    """
    try:
        with open(input_file_name) as input_file:
            lines = input_file.readlines()


        n = len(lines)
        x = list(range(n))
        for i in range(n):

            x[i] = lines[i].strip()
        a = []
        b = []

        if x is None:
            raise TypeError
            a = None
            b = None

        else:
            for i in x:
                c,d = i.split(",")
                a.append(float(c))
                b.append(float(d))


        return a,b

    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("Unable to open and read '{}'".format(input_file_name))

    except ValueError:
        print("Unable to open and read '{}'".format(input_file_name))
```

When I make this function to handle the exception it gives me a Type Error. 
For example:

```py
    e,f = read_data('lol')
```

```
Unable to open and read 'lol'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#7>", line 1, in <module>
    e,f = read_data('lol')
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object
```

How can I make this function handle an exception if a file doesn't exist and make the function return a tuple of two Nones and output: 'Unable to open and read'?

Comment: You haven't really handled the two errors you catch; you've just acknowledged and ignored them. You should re-raise them, or not catch them in the first place.

Comment: Also, `a = None`, `b = None` after you raise the `TypeError` are never executed and serve no purpose.

Answer (score 2):

after you catch the exception, you didn't return anything(it means you return NoneType). But you try to unpack return values(NoneType). So it throws exception.

so avoid this exception, you raise exception again or return a, b again.

```py
except (FileNotFoundError, ValueError) as e:
        print("Unable to open and read '{}'".format(input_file_name))
        # throw exception again
        raise e
```

or

```py
# outside of try-except
a, b = [], []

try:

# ...

except (FileNotFoundError, ValueError) as e:
        print("Unable to open and read '{}'".format(input_file_name))
        # return a tuple of empty lists
        return a, b
```

Comment: Now it gives this error
except (FileNotFoundError | ValueError) as e:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'type' and 'type'

Comment: @Chinna oh, sorry my mistakes, use "," instead of "|".